# how can i remove item from my collection in java

Tags: java

```
    Members m = new Members(membersId, membersName, membersAge,
            membersGender);
    lib.addnewMembers(m);
```

how can I add remove method?
how can I  remove anything just by giving **membersId** ?
and I used iterator in my library.java this is my code to add members in my collection:

@Override

```
public String toString() {
    String total = "\n";
    Iterator<Members> i = collection.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Members m = (Members) i.next();
        total = total + m.toString();
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Please add more code or more information.

Comment: I suggest you edit your post and be more specific

Comment: Perhaps https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterators-in-java/ this will help you bring more information regarding the attributes of Iterator

Answer (score 0):

Remove method is something like:

```java
//java8
public void remove(List<Member> members, long memberId) {
   members.stream().filter(m -> !m.getId() == memberId).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
//group Ids to delete
public void remove(List<Member> members, List<Long> memberIds) {
   members.stream().filter(m -> !memberIds.contains(m.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// before java8
public void remove(List<Member> members, long memberId) {
   Iterator<Member> mi = members.iteator();
   while (mi.hasNext()){
      Member m = mi.next();
      if(m.getId() == memberId) {
          mi.remove();
      }
   }
}
public void remove(List<Member> members, List<Long> memberIds) {
   Iterator<Member> mi = members.iteator();
   while (mi.hasNext()){
      Member m = mi.next();
      if(memberIds.contains(m.getId())) {
          mi.remove();
      }
   }
}
```